# How to use RequestRestartAsync(String) Method in C++

Tags: c++, uwp

I am writing an UWP app which can select a binary file and print out its data after some processing procedure. It now can read data correcting for the first time but when I open another file through file picker it can not read correctly. So I am considering get the app restart every time before I select a file.

I found these code below in C# that seems helpful but I want to write a C++ version.

Since sample code resource is so limited for C++, is there anyway to convert the provided C# sample code into C++?

```
private async void DoMajorAppReconfiguration()
{
    // Attempt restart, with arguments.
    AppRestartFailureReason result =
        await CoreApplication.RequestRestartAsync("-fastInit -level 1 -foo");

    // Restart request denied, send a toast to tell the user to restart manually.
    if (result == AppRestartFailureReason.NotInForeground
        || result == AppRestartFailureReason.Other)
    {
        SendToast("Please manually restart.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read data from a file again after the file picker open another file, you could put the file into `StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList` property(MRU) as soon as you pick it. You can get a token string when you add a file into the MRU by using `StorageItemMostRecentlyUsedList.Add` method, and retrieve the item from the MRU with the token string in other position. For example,

```
hstring mruToken{};// mruToken can be a global variable
```

Add the file into MRU after pick,

```
Windows::Storage::Pickers::FileOpenPicker picker{};
picker.ViewMode(Windows::Storage::Pickers::PickerViewMode::Thumbnail);
picker.SuggestedStartLocation(Pickers::PickerLocationId::Desktop);
picker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L"*");
StorageFile file = co_await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

if (file != nullptr)
{
   mruToken = Windows::Storage::AccessCache::StorageApplicationPermissions::MostRecentlyUsedList().Add(file);
}
```

Get the file added into MRU in another position with `mruToken`,

```
auto myitem = Windows::Storage::AccessCache::StorageApplicationPermissions::MostRecentlyUsedList().GetFileAsync(mruToken);
StorageFile myfile= myitem.GetResults();
```

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If it is not solved, please feel free to contact us.